# Resize Highchart but still keep the details inside

Tags: jquery, html, charts, highcharts

I would like to ask is there a solution to resize the highchart to a smaller size but still keep the details within the chart ? I'm developing a page which contains a small chart, but it will display as a bigger chart when the user clicks on it.

What i did was to set the width of the div contains the chart but the content inside is not displayed properly (The whole chart is resized)

So I would be greatful to know that there is a function or property of highchart which can let me do so.

Expected result : Click to small chart (but details) to the bigger one
[image]

What I did to the width of Div :

[image]

Comment: I created a simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5j6cq1v2/ which includes width as 100%. Let me know if that is correct?